# Get the left indentation of a line above the selection - VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have to format a text based on indentation.

The steps are :

1. User selects a table on a page
2. Presses a button
3. The table gets indented exactly as the text above ( no gaps at all)

I know MSFT gives little less indentation to the table, so they look little askew. 
I know how to change the indent of the selected table by the command

```
 Selection.Tables(1).Rows.LeftIndent = <Value_as_that_of_the_text_above>
```

but I don't know how do I get the indentation of the text above, considering only table has been selected not the text above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to go to the paragraph above then set the indent? That should give you the basic code, just modify it to read instead of set the indent.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get all the paragraphs of the document([try this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211455)). Then get the last paragraph on the page indent.